# Error al cargar dotnet.wasm en Blazor WebAssembly

Tags: iis, error404, blazor, dotnetcore, .net-5

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Al momento de publicar mi aplicación Blazor WebAssembly no se puede visualizar ya que no permite la carga del archivo dotnet.wasm y con ello ocasiona errores en la integridad de los archivos SHA-256 y verificación de integridad.

Answer (score 0):

Con respecto al tema, les informo, resulta que para las versiones más recientes de .NET se requiere un software adicional que reescribe la URL, este software es URL Rewrite.

En mi caso estoy publicando con .NET 5 y por lo mismo ya modifica la manera de cargar a como lo hacía en .NET Core 2 y/o 3, este software lo pueden descargar de
https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite
una vez descargado sólo instalar en el servidor y solucionado